# Fail Gradle Build for Sonar Violations

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

How do I configure my Gradle build to fail when there are Sonar violations?

I want my Gradle build to fail if there are any are any critical or blocker violations in Sonar, is this functionality supported? If so, is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not something that can be configured on the build side. Instead, the "build breaker plugin" has to be configured on the Sonar side. I'm not completely sure if it works with Gradle, but I think it does.

Answer (score 7):

1) You must install the **Build Breaker Plugin** on the server side into **/path/to/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/** see full instruction here

https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker

2) you must use the SonarQube Scanner for Gradle

3) In your gradle config **sonar.buildbreaker.skip** properties must be **false**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    ...
        maven {
            // for sonarqube
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }   
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
        properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "your.project"  
        property "sonar.buildbreaker.skip" , "false"
        }
}
```

4) You will probably want to add a Quality Gate in sonarQube (server side). For more information check this

Comment: Would you mind to update your link build breaker git link? 
The project is not working for newer sonar versions (>7) for over a year now:
https://github.com/jbocc/sonar-build-breaker/issues/44

Here is the link to the newer working repository version:
https://github.com/adnovum/sonar-build-breaker

Answer (score 0):

Add a quality gate to the project and include `sonar.qualitygate.wait`:

```java
// build.gradle
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.qualitygate.wait", true)
```

Source: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/ ("Quality Gate",  bottom of the page)