# Sonarlint Gradle Task - Execution failed for task ':sonarlintMain'

Tags: java, gradle, sonarlint

Trying to use 'sonarlintMain' using Gradle 7.0.2_2 on 'openjdk version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19'

```
id ("name.remal.sonarlint") version "1.3.1"
```

Runs & displays:

```
> Task :sonarlintMain

219 SonarLint violations were found

[rank 1] [java:S2095] /Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/GoStopHandle/src/main/java/com/gostophandle/ejb/DatabaseSchemaJSON.java:115:30
  Resources should be closed

  Connections, streams, files, and other classes that implement the Closeable interface or its
  super-interface, AutoCloseable, needs to be closed after use. Further, that close call must be
  made in a finally block otherwise an exception could keep the call from being made. Preferably,
  when class implements AutoCloseable, resource should be created using "try-with-resources"
  pattern and will be closed automatically.

  Failure to properly close resources will result in a resource leak which could bring first the
  application and then perhaps the box the application is on to their knees.

etc ...
```

At end shows:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarlintMain'.
> 219 SonarLint violations were found

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 32s
```

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.co:

```
1 task failure
The :sonarlintMain task failed.View task in console log
219 SonarLint violations were found
```

Comment: It looks like it worked to me. The sonarLintMain task failed because you have issues with your Java code which have generated warnings. The sonarLintMain task has "failed" so that your build doesn't create an artifact that has these issues. Correct your Java code and the sonarLintMain task will succeed. Only 219 issues - shouldn't take too long ;-)

Comment: id ("checkstyle"), id ("com.github.spotbugs") version "4.7.1" & id ("pmd") works fine & creates my WAR, JAR  & EAR. Deploys and runs on WildFly. Looks like I need to get 'sonarlint' to just show 'warnings'.  TIA.

Comment: It seems like you have the opposite issue to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936019/fail-gradle-build-for-sonar-violations

Answer (score 0):

Found: https://remal.gitlab.io/gradle-plugins/plugins/name.remal.sonarlint/

Added:

```
sonarlint {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

Runs:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 34s
18 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

Need more documentation etc. but will pass for the time.